# create object from processor output to append/replaceChild

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xslt

Attempting to add parameters to an xsl template, for use in a navigation menu.

Trying to figure out how to use the output that IXSLProcessor leaves me with.

I have the following code that works perfectly for Firefox

```
var xslStylesheet;
    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    var myDOM;
    var xmlDoc;
    var myXMLHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myXMLHTTPRequest.open("GET", "client.xsl", false);
    myXMLHTTPRequest.send(null);

    xslStylesheet = myXMLHTTPRequest.responseXML;
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);

    // load the xml file
    myXMLHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myXMLHTTPRequest.open("GET", "client.xml", false);
    myXMLHTTPRequest.send(null);
    xmlDoc = myXMLHTTPRequest.responseXML;

    // set the parameter using the parameter passed to the outputgroup function
    xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "cid", client);
    xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "browser", "other");
    var fragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc,document);
    document.getElementById("scriptHook").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("maincontent").replaceChild(fragment, document.getElementById("scriptHook"));
    scroll(0,0);
```

This is the code I have (mostly pilfered from msdn)

```
var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.3.0");
var xsldoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0");
var xslproc;
xsldoc.async = false;
xsldoc.load("client.xsl");
if (xsldoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
   var myErr = xsldoc.parseError;
   WScript.Echo("You have error " + myErr.reason);
} else {
   xslt.stylesheet = xsldoc;
   var xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
   xmldoc.async = false;
   xmldoc.load("client.xml");
   if (xmldoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
      var myErr = xmldoc.parseError;
      WScript.Echo("You have error " + myErr.reason);
   } else {
      xslproc = xslt.createProcessor();
      xslproc.input = xmldoc;
      xslproc.addParameter("cid", client);
      xslproc.addParameter("browser", "ie");
      xslproc.transform();

      //somehow convert xslproc.output to object that can be used in replaceChild

      document.getElementById("scriptHook").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("maincontent").replaceChild(xslproc.output, document.getElementById("scriptHook"));

     }
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Mozilla you can exchange nodes between XSLT and DOM but with IE you need to take the XSLT transformation result as a string and feed that to IE's HTML parser; so for your sample I think you want

```
document.getElementById("scriptHook").outerHTML = xslproc.output;
```

which will replace the `scriptHook` element with the result of the transformation.

Comment: outerHTML eh? I've not come across this before, is this an MSXML exclusive member is it?

Many thanks for your reply, will chuck it in and see where it that does the trick.

Comment: Fantastic, that did it. Why on earth I didnt think of that is beyond me! Cheers mate.

Comment: `outerHTML` is a property in the IE/MSHTML DOM since IE 4 and I think is also supported by other browsers by now, with Firefox/Mozilla being the last https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML to introduce it (supposedly because HTML5 specifies it http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#outerhtml).

Comment: Thanks for that Martin, admittedly I have not kept up to date with the HTML5 specs.